# On validation exception data is getting clear from all fields, FormView, Grid etc

Tags: acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have a form its implemented the Revision number logic as Acumatica suggest,  when any validation exception thrown on saving the data then it clear all fields value from Grid and FormView, How may i resolve this issue?

Comment: Well, probably something is not implemented properly in Key fields of the DAC. Check implementation of Kit assembly screen that uses Revisions.

Comment: I saw Bill of material, its clearing data there also. Kit Assembly using Projection.